# Extra items being returned from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json, select

I am performing a select query from my database as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.room_type_id,  rt.room_type_name FROM ROOM as r JOIN ROOM_TYPE as rt 
    ON r.room_type_id = rt.room_type_id Where r.homestead_id = 1
    AND (SELECT Count(*) FROM TENANT as t WHERE r.room_id = t.room_id) < room_capacity 
    AND (room_gender = 'male' OR room_gender='both')
```

it returns:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| room_type_id | room_type_name |
+--------------+----------------+
|            1 | Two-bedroom    |
+--------------+----------------+
```

This is exactly what I want. But when I run this through my php:

```
function getAvailableRoomTypes($homesteadID,$gender){
    global $con;
    $roomtypes = array();
    //this gets only available rooms
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT r.room_type_id,  rt.room_type_name FROM ROOM as r JOIN ROOM_TYPE as rt 
    ON r.room_type_id = rt.room_type_id Where r.homestead_id = $homesteadID
    AND (SELECT Count(*) FROM TENANT as t WHERE r.room_id = t.room_id) < room_capacity 
    AND (room_gender = '$gender' OR room_gender='both')";
    $result  = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $roomtypes += $row;
    }
    var_dump($roomtypes);
    return $roomtypes;
}
```

I get this for my var_dump:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["room_type_id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(11) "Two-bedroom" ["room_type_name"]=> string(11) "Two-bedroom" }
```

I was expecting to only recieve this:

```
array(4) {["room_type_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["room_type_name"]=> string(11) "Two-bedroom" }
```

What is that extra information?
How can I get rid of it so I only get the pure information?

I will be converting the array into a JSON object afterwards and I want it to only have the necessary parts.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL code, read up on [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You cannot simply insert user data like `$gender` into your query.

Comment: The default result type for [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) is `MYSQLI_BOTH`. I suggest you read the documentation carefully

Comment: Thank you for the bind_param suggestion. I WILL do that. I am doing some more research on MYSQLI_BOTH and what that entails. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.